# Setting property based on system architecture in burn

Tags: wix

In my bundle I have a variable that holds the default installation path. I then use this variable to show the default path in my custom BA as well as I pass it to MSI package. The problem I'm facing right now is that I want to have a different value per architecture, basically [ProgramFiles64Folder] for 64 bit machines and [ProgramFilesFolder] for 32 bit.

The code I have so far is:

```
// if 64 bit
<Variable Name="installationpath" Value="[ProgramFiles64Folder]$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)"/>
// else
<Variable Name="installationpath" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)"/>

<Chain>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\32.msi" Id="client32" Cache="yes" Visible="no" Vital="yes" InstallCondition="Installed OR NOT VersionNT64">
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[installationpath]" />
  </MsiPackage>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\64.msi" Id="client64" Cache="yes" Visible="no" Vital="yes" InstallCondition="Installed OR VersionNT64">
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[installationpath]" />
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

This is the if condition I'm struggling with. Is there a way at all to do it with single variable, or do I need 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [`ProgramFiles6432Folder` variable](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html) instead and let Burn handle it.

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I haven't noticed that one, thanks